# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am using the latest version of Facebbok Sdk,i.e. 4.8.0, for sharing the photos from my app. Everything is working fine if I have Facebook App installed on my device, but it is showing warning

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"

if I uninstall Facebook App, and I am no longer able to share photos.
     I have also configured my info.plist like this ->

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

I have also gone through various links, but nothing helped me.
Thanx for any help in advance.

Comment: Have you checked in device??

Comment: i m checking in device

Comment: Is your problem is only in ios9 if YES then have you add NSAppTransportSecurity in your plist?

Comment: I have already added it

Answer (score 2):

Have u added this one

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb518113611684599</string>
            <string>fbauth2</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
```

Comment: Thanx for ur reply. But I m now started getting this error ->  LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme fbapi20130214

Comment: Once test the app in device.

Comment: I simply want to share photos through my Facebook app, if it installed, otherwise Share Button should direct me to Safari.

Comment: I am testing on device

Comment: For Share button you need to get permission from Facebook.

Comment: If Facebook App is installed, then I am able to use Share Button, then why I am not able to use it when app is not installed. According to Facebook docs, it should be done.

Comment: That one I also didn't understand.I will try and tell you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98534/discussion-between-user5452972-and-uma-madhavi).

Comment: same as @user5452972, I'm now started getting this error -> LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme fbapi20130214

Comment: This answer is not just incorrect, but will cause your app to actively screw up FB Login for other apps. You should *not* be implementing the fbauth2 protocol yourself. For the best chance of success without fouling up other apps trying to log in, follow the Facebook documentation and test on an actual device with the Facebook app installed.